# python2 sockets can't connect to python3 sockets

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, sockets

I was trying to code a simple server client program in python and when i ran the server using python3 and tried to have the client connect to it using python2, it would throw an error:

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

however, when i ran the same short program on the same computer using python2 and python3, it would connect.  The 2 separate computers would only connect if they were using the same version of python.  Is there a reason for this and a way around this?

```
#client
s=socket.socket()
s.connect(('ip, port))

#server
s=socket()
s.bind(('', port))
s.listen(4)
c, addr = s.accept()
```

Comment: Maybe python.exe is allowed in your firewall software but python3.exe is not?

Comment: @JohnZwinck oh that did the trick! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows software firewall has python.exe marked as allowed but not python3.exe.